# EPPlus чтение файла

Tags: c#, epplus

Для работы с excel использую EPPlus. В отдельном потоке создается файл и сразу же читается (path корректный, файла точно не существует):

```cs
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)) // запрещаем другим править файл
{
    excelPack.Load(stream); // excelPack создается до этого
}
```

При этом ошибка доступа к файлу. Не могу понять причину. Как тогда правильно создать файл и сразу же прочитать его? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ну, вероятно он просто у вас открыт в этот момент

Comment: `using (var stream = File.Create(path))` и ничего лишнего не добавляйте, там и так все так, как вам надо. Только файл пустой создается, в нем ничего нет, нечего читать. Обычно такие файлы создаются для записи, а не для чтения.